# WP8 Beta App Database not listed in Isolated Store

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a WP8 to test my developed apps.

I have 2 apps installed: one deployed by VS2013 and another by Windows Store Beta App.

The app installed by VS2013 appears on IsoStoreSpy or Windows Phone Power Tools programs and I can copy the database.

The other one installed by Windows Store (beta app download), I can't find the Database and the ID of the app not appears in IsoStoreSpy or WP Power tools.

Is there any problem with apps installed by store to get the data from isolated store ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the drill..!

You can not play with any of internal Data of Windows Phone application which is installed from Windows Phone Store, irrespective of the app is BETA or Public.

Once you upload the app package to Store, Microsoft will Encrypt the App package and make it non Extractable anyhow..! Whereas the App Package generated by Visual Studio is extractable and can be accessed by any developer tool as you mentioned like WP Power Tools.

That's the security purpose.

For more reference check below links.

[Isolated Storage - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is a problem for me! This is the reason I need to move to Android development, in MS I can just update remotely an app if the client uses Win8, because all the tools that I know use WP8 SDK to update the app. The problem is that company users generally uses Win7! So the only way I get to update the app is to publish as Beta and send the link by email to my customer update. But the problem is if I need to copy the databse first, for check for any problems or even to get the data, I can't copy like you said, for security reason.

Comment: This is why all the developers is choosing to use Android, for the business needs is much more flexible than WP! Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You could have a feature in your app to upload the file to a web service or via the Share contract.